# if print_r is empty conditional in PHP

Tags: php, count, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get a n else statement working with a print_r such that if there's no value it outputs "no values".
In the code I'm getting values from json converted to an array.
The logic I'm trying to achieve is
IF fieldTag contains "i" THEN output the content associated with it
ELSE says its empty.
Right now blank is outputted as opposed to "no values".
Thanks

```
for($b=0; $b<count($res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields']); $b++) //loop thru the varFields            
{
    if($res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields'][$b]['fieldTag'] == "i")
    {                       
        $subfieldText2 = $res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields'][$b]['subfields'][0]['content']."<br>";
        if(count($subfieldText2) > 0) { 
            print_r($subfieldText2); 
        } else { 
            echo "no values";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what problem are you having

Comment: If the `fieldTag` is `i`, you're setting `$subfieldText2` to a non-empty string (you always appending a `<br>` to it). `count()` [will be `1`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php#refsect1-function.count-returnvalues) in that case (with a PHP warning), so the `print_r()` case is always entered. If the original `['subfields'][0]['content']` string was empty, you're printing only `<br>`s which would look like blank output in your browser.

Comment: where is $i defined?

Comment: `$subfieldText2` is a string, not an array, so `count()` makes no sense. Maybe you mean `strlen()`? But you concatenate `"<br>"` to it, so the length will always be at least 4.

Comment: $i is the entries number....first entry, second entry...derived from a for loop

Answer (score 0):

`count()` is for arrays, not strings, the way to get the length of a string is with `strlen()`. And if you want to check for an empty string, just compare it with `$var == ""`, you don't need to get the length.

But you're concatenating `"<br>"` to the value, so the length will never be zero. You could check the length *before* concatenating.

```
$subfieldText2 = $res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields'][$b]['subfields'][0]['content'];
if($subfieldText2 != "") { 
    $subfieldText2 .= "<br>";
    print_r($subfieldText2); 
} else { 
    echo "no values";
}
```

And to avoid having to repeat that long expression to access the field, you could use `foreach`

```
for($res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields'] as $field) {
    if ($field['fieldTag'] == "i") {
        $subfieldText2 = $field['subfields'][0]['content'];
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me thanks everyone

```
$subfieldText2="not detected";

          echo "ISBN: ";
                for($b=0; $b<count($res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields']); $b++) //loop thru the varFields
                                    {
                                      if($res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields'][$b]['fieldTag'] == "i")
                                            {

                                            $subfieldText2 = $res['entries'][$i]['bib']['varFields'][$b]['subfields'][0]['content'];
                                            echo $subfieldText2.", ";

                                            }
                                      }

            echo $subfieldText2;
```